# Outlining (OpenGL 2.0)

Tags: opengl

From what I know of there are 2 ways to outline a set of verticies, by using a shader or using a stencil buffer.

Example 1: stencil buffer: in this image, [img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mx8xh.png)
the outlines overlap each other but you could change the colors of each outline.

Example 2: shader: in this image, [img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRr0v.png)
the outlines do not overlap, but you could not change colors for each outline.

is there a way to combine those two, like a way to change the colors for each outline yet prevent them from overlapping?

(also ignore the fact that I took the images from minecraft)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to add an outline is to draw the same mesh twice: once normally and once with a solid color shader, with the same transform (meaning same location, same rotation), but slightly scaled up, and with its faces flipped by changing the winding order with `glFrontFace(GL_CW)` (default is `GL_CCW` - counter-clock wise) before drawing the model. This creates a sort of "hull" around the model, with only its back face visible. The front face is transparent (culled).

The stencil approach is to "mask out" a part of the frame. It's better described [here](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Stencil-testing). Basically you enable the stencil mask, draw the model (which creates a "hole" in the stencil buffer with the same shape as the model, of where ***not*** to draw fragments later on), then later in the frame you draw the same model again, same transform, but slightly scaled up, and with a solid color shader (e.g. yellow). And where that "hole" in the stencil buffer is, it gets cut, leaving behind just the outline part of the scaled up yellow mesh (or whatever color you want).

Another approach is using signed distance fields (SDF) by rendering the model to a separate texture using a solid color shader, then turning it into an SDF and using a uniform in the fragment shader to control a "range" of where to place the outline (e.g. between 0.0 and 0.05). Zero is right at the edge of the model, negative values are inside of it. It's commonly used with rendering text but it can be used with anything. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1b5hIMqz_wM) video explains how they work.

All of the outline methods EASILY allow you to change the color. Are you trying to develop a cheat? If you don't have access to the source code of the game I can't help you.